# How can I camera track this shot without the specific camera information?

Tags: camera, tracking

I have this shot (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=32yceqsS4_Q) which I need to place a building into. I sadly do not know the details of the camera, and am not very experienced with camera tracking. Is there going to be a way to do it? I'm not able to use a different shot.

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. If you provide enough marker points tracks (8 at least for a shot with camera in motion like this) the solver should be able to give a good apprixmation of the values without knowing the specs. Did you tried? Wasn't it working?

Comment: @Carlo Thanks, I did try that, and I didn't get great results. Either the camera was upside down (no idea why) or the whole scene seemed to be on an angle, or looking from far too high above. Should I be placing markers in the trees as well, or just on the ground?

Comment: Markers should be placed where they may be useful and nicely tracked. They can be everywhere, but you should spread them along several viewing plane of the shot to get great parallax and good solving. Here's my try: https://imgur.com/a/iCrbH Without further information we'll not be able to guess what you are doing wrong. I'll suggest to edit your question and better describe your workflow, your markers choice, their graph, ecc...

Comment: You can probably do a decent job without knowing the camera sensor size or lens and letting blender calculate something. The crucial thing is having accurate tracking. Read the following link for a comprehensive post on motion tracking tips: [How can I get better results when doing camera motion tracking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking/42332#42332)